# jQuery Fullcalendar and ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I need help with Fullcalendar

I tried colored some days, this days are in database, I have this code in controller

```
public JsonResult GetEventsSVN(double start, double end, int id){
//id variable is a test
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id);
            Evento calendario = new Evento();
            var starDateTime = calendario.FromUnixTimestamp(start);
            var endDateTime = calendario.FromUnixTimestamp(end);
            using(SVN_RDCEntities db = new SVN_RDCEntities()){
                var query = from evento in db.TEvento
                            where evento.EventoInicio > starDateTime && evento.EventoFin < endDateTime
                            select evento;
                var listaEvento = new List<object>();
                foreach(var item in query){
                    listaEvento.Add(new{
                        id = item.PkEventoId,
                        title = item.EventoHora,
                        start = calendario.ConvertToTimestamp(item.EventoInicio),
                        end = calendario.ConvertToTimestamp(item.EventoFin),
                    });
                }
                return Json(listaEvento.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

In view have a problem in `daysRender` function. The AJAX call inside does not function.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ids = "1";
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'title',
                //center: false/*'month',agendaWeek,agendaDay'*/
            },
            editable: false,
            events: {
                url: '/Evento/GetEvents/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: ids }
            },
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.find('.fc-event-title').append("&nbsp;<a href = Evento/Details/" + event.id + " class = 'link-calendario'><i class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></a>");
            },
            dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '/Evento/GetEventsSVN/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id: ids },
                    success: function (data) {
                        date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]').addClass('cellBg');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            language: "es",
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            calendarWeeks: true,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to make an AJAX call to for search this days, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: How does the call not work? Perhaps add error handling and see what is going wrong? Is it hitting your backend at all? Where is `ids` variable set?

Comment: ids is a test... i can change the question and put the complet javascript sorry.

Comment: Why are you doing an ajax post each time an event is being rendered?